# Editing php.ini to instal Xdebug

Tags: xdebug

All,

I'm a relative newbie programmer and I want to install Xdebug to help me debug my PHP work. I'm using Wamp on a Windows XP machine.

I uploaded the content of my phpinfo() onto the Xdebug site, and as part of the tailored installation instructions I get:

> Edit `C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.11\bin\php.ini` and add the line
>   `zend_extension =
>   c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0\ext\php_xdebug-2.1.2-5.3-vc6.dll`

I have never opened that file before, and when I open it I find that every single setting is placed in a paragraph with some comments - for example:

```
[Tidy]
; The path to a default tidy configuration file to use when using tidy
; http://php.net/tidy.default-config
;tidy.default_config = /usr/local/lib/php/default.tcfg

; Should tidy clean and repair output automatically?
; WARNING: Do not use this option if you are generating non-html content
; such as dynamic images
; http://php.net/tidy.clean-output
tidy.clean_output = Off
```

So should I type something like that:

```
[Xdebug]
; This is the line to be inserted per the set-up instructions (2012-01-05)
zend_extension = c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0\ext\php_xdebug-2.1.2-5.3-vc6.dll
```

I assume the `[...]` and the `;` are not read by the server but I'm really not sure what they are and I don't want to screw things up...

Thanks,

JDelage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you only need the one line. Sections [..] and ; are ignored in PHP's parser. So all you need is:

```
zend_extension = c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0\ext\php_xdebug-2.1.2-5.3-vc6.dll
```

cheers.
Derick